# HTML code appended to JSON output perhaps due to Google Docs Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-docs

Testing a page on a different computer to mine, I noticed that some Ajax request wasn't working.  Looking in the console, I found that there was some HTML code at the end of the JSON string.  It appears to be something to do with Google Docs.  I checked, and this code is appended to every web page, it seems.  How can I stop this code being added to JSON output, though?  It obviously throws a syntax error as jQuery tries to interpret it as JSON.

This blob of code is appended to JSON output:

```
<div class="ugdv_contextMenu" id="ugdv_myMenu" style="display: none; ">
    <ul id="ugdv_contextMenu">
        <li id="ugdv_menuItem_google_docs">Open in Google Docs Viewer</li>
        <li id="ugdv_menuItem_new_tab">Open link in new tab</li>
        <li id="ugdv_menuItem_new_window">Open link in new window</li>
        <li id="ugdv_menuItem_new_incognito">Open link in new incognito window</li>
        <li class="ugdv_seperator"></li><li id="ugdv_menuItem_download_file">Download file</li>
        <li id="ugdv_menuItem_copy">Copy link address</li>
        <li id="ugdv_menuItem_editpdf">Edit PDF File on PDFescape.com</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So, does anyone know what it is and how I   can get rid of it?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you have a poorly written extension.  Can you list the extensions you have enabled in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know why this HTML is getting appended, the solution should be simple enough: don't specify `JSON` as the data type in your ajax request. In fact, don't specify any type at all. Just do the following in your success callback:

```
success: function(response){
    var responseArray = response.split('<div');
    var jsonString = response[0];
    var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with JSON.  It seems to appear only with Chrome IF you've enabled Google doc support.  (This was driving me crazy until I realized it was the Google Docs context menu - ok, I'm slow.  Didn't show up until I enabled docs; doesn't show up on other browsers.  I spent an eternity making changes to my ajax success code until I realized it was beyond my control.  The problem I'm seeing is that if I try to append an img or link to a div, the div for the context menu is appended to the end of my filename, causing html errors.

E.g. given `$('<li></li>').appendTo('#xxx').html('<img src="foo.com/bar.jpg" alt="" />` the context menu div starts right after the .jpg.